# Does expo React-native securestore returns an objects for a string value?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

how do I get the string value of a TOKEN I saved to the expo-SecureStore using the following code as documented on their page

Functions

```
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

export async function save(key, value) {
  try {
    const data = await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

export async function getValueFor(key) {
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  if (result) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

> ! ####################
> Calling function

```
 try {
      const res = await axios.post("/token/", data);
      await save("jwt_access", "");
      await save("jwt_refresh", res.data.refresh);
      return resolve(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error.message);
    }
```

```
getValueFor("jwt_access")

getValueFor("jwt_refresh")
```

Output

```
 {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null} //for access token
 {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 1, 
   "_z": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjcxNDEylcm1lbmVudF9yZXNpZGVudCI6dHJ1ZX0.sy9KrdOnplUbnwe1Col3Vchlja7XwSM36hesmWkEclg"
} //for refresh token
```

how do i get just the token alone an not the object

Comment: debug `save()` while saving the token data. I suspect you storing this entire object while saving..

Comment: If your output data is `[{},{}]`, you should get it with `const token = res[1]._z`

Comment: the save function is called within an try_catch block in an async function, and only a token was passed to it as an argument.

Comment: getValueFor("jwt_access") return promise. Await it to get resolved.`const jwt_acces =  await getValueFor("jwt_access")`

Comment: thank you guys for helping out, Found the cause, I was calling outside an async func ... thanks @Fiston Emmanuel

Comment: Cool, Glad you figure out